# filter value from json data in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter value from JSON data in python(totally new to python and learning in progress).

I've used "GET" request with my required "querystring" and I got my output successfully no issues with that part:

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)

output:

```
[{'Name': 'george',
'place': 'koti',
'street': 2,
'status':'single'},
{'Name': 'george2',
'place': 'Amberpet',
'street': 3,
'status':'Married'},
{'Name': 'george3',
'place': 'suryapet',
'street': 8,
'status':'engaged'}]
```

so, the output type is "list".  Now, from that list I want to filter out "Name" i.e.., when printing the value only  "Name" should be the output.

can someone please help?

Thanks,
Madhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list_ is your desired output

```py
output  = [{'Name': 'george',
'place': 'koti',
'street': 2,
'status':'single'},
{'Name': 'george2',
'place': 'Amberpet',
'street': 3,
'status':'Married'},
{'Name': 'george3',
'place': 'suryapet',
'street': 8,
'status':'engaged'}]

list_ = [dict_['Name'] for dict_ in output]

print(list_)
```

output:

```
['george', 'george2', 'george3']
```